# ScrollView can host only one direct child - android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, scrollview

i want to add ScrollView into my layout as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true" 
    android:fadingEdgeLength="1dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/medium_gray">

   <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true" 
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/unitlink1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:divider="#000000"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:text="RINGKASAN DANA TRANSAKSI"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout

                    style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight=".40"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                    android:paddingTop="5dip" >

                    <!-- Kolom 1 -->

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                        android:paddingTop="10dip"
                        android:text="Jenis dana Transaksi"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="17sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- Kolom 2 -->

                <LinearLayout

                    style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight=".30"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                    android:paddingTop="5dip" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                        android:paddingTop="10dip"
                        android:text="Total Unit"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                        android:text="Harga Unit"
                        android:textColor="#b5b5b5"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- Kolom 3 -->

                <LinearLayout

                    style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight=".30"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                    android:paddingTop="5dip" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/jumlah_unit1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                        android:paddingTop="10dip"
                        android:text="Nilai POLIS"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/harga_unit1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                        android:text="Tanggal NAB"
                        android:textColor="#b5b5b5"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <include layout="@layout/line" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:divider="#000000"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:focusable="false" />
            </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>


   <!-- 5 Tabel Dari Unit Link-->   
    <!-- <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/unitlink2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"> -->

   <!-- Excellink Aggressive Fund -->  
         <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true" 
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/unitlink3"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical" 
              android:visibility="visible">

     <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/title1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:text="Excellink Aggressive Fund"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:divider="#000000"
                 android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

   <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <LinearLayout

            style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight=".40"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip">

        <!--Kolom 1-->
        <TextView
            android:text="Transaksi"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Kolom 2 -->
        <LinearLayout

                style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight=".30"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip" >

        <TextView
            android:text="Jumlah"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:gravity="right" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Tanggal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#b5b5b5"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>
    </LinearLayout> 

        <!-- Kolom 3 -->
    <LinearLayout

                style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"              
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight=".30"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jumlah_unit1"
            android:text="Jumlah Unit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip" 
            android:gravity="right"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/harga_unit1"
            android:text="Harga Unit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#b5b5b5"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>
        <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <include layout="@layout/line"/>
            </LinearLayout>

       <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"/>
       </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>

  <!-- Excellink Dynamic Fund -->   
   <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true" 
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">  
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/unitlink4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         android:visibility="visible">

     <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/title1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:text="Excellink Dynamic Fund"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:divider="#000000"
                 android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

   <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <LinearLayout

            style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight=".40"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip">

        <!--Kolom 1-->
        <TextView
            android:text="Transaksi"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Kolom 2 -->
        <LinearLayout

                style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight=".30"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip" >

        <TextView
            android:text="Jumlah"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:gravity="right" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Tanggal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#b5b5b5"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>
    </LinearLayout> 

        <!-- Kolom 3 -->
    <LinearLayout

                style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"              
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight=".30"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jumlah_unit1"
            android:text="Jumlah Unit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip" 
            android:gravity="right"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/harga_unit1"
            android:text="Harga Unit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#b5b5b5"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>
        <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <include layout="@layout/line"/>
            </LinearLayout>

       <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"/>
       </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>
```

but when i run it, scrollview just scroll my layout, not my listview. i want the scrollview scroll my layout, and other scrollview, scroll my listview. how to solve it? thanks before

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:divider="#000000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"/>
```

to:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:divider="#000000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:focusable="false" >
</ListView>
```

And put it outside (after) the `<ScrollView>` `<!-- Excellink Dynamic Fund -->`

The XML from the bottom looks something like this:

```
...
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <include layout="@layout/line" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:divider="#000000"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:focusable="false" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Let me know,
Cheers.

Comment: can you explain again what are you trying to achieve? Is it that the ListView is not moving? like you only see 2 element where you actually have 10? or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is a mess! You are trying to solve the wrong problem, you shouldn't add a ScrollView to scroll a ListView!

You have 4 ScrollViews and 3 ListViews on the same layout, you definitely need to rework it!